# Oracle APEX 23.1: How to change the email body when downloading

Tags: oracle-apex

In APEX 23.1 Inerative Grid, Go to Actions → Download → email (check the email box). The email received has email body as below:

Text entered in message body while downloading.
This email sent by USERID
http://host/pls/apex/f?p=101:11
Is there a way to remove the last two lines from the email body?

I asked in Oracle forum also but no response. I thought this would be some simple setup!

I tried putting email text while sending but that does not override the default text and link.

Comment: afaik you have no control over what is generated for download out of the box. That feature is just there for convenience. If you want  your own email/content, then you'll have to write your own code - that is definitely possible.